# STM32 VBAT ADC voltage measurement incorrect at low voltages

Tags: adc, stm32, stm32f4

I have a problem with VBAT voltage measurement on a STM32F401VB.
As can be seen in the picture below, the ADC output is correct (identical to the calculated value "ADC Should") in the upper region of the input voltage, but incorrect when the input voltage drops below approximately 1V.
[image: graph]
At 0V input voltage the ADC value is 239 when it should be close to zero.
The other ADC channels work as expected, so I think this has something to do with the internal VBAT circuitry.

Does anybody know what this could be caused by?

Comment: What is the source impedance and how is it connected?  This looks like a Schottky diode drop.

Comment: " the
V BAT pin is internally connected to a bridge divider by 2. This bridge is automatically enabled
when VBATEN is set, to connect V BAT /2 to the ADC1_IN17 input channel. As a
consequence, the converted digital value is half the V BAT voltage."  Looks like an internal ST issue on IN17 sensing near gnd.

Comment: the internal divider has quite high impedance and long sampling time is needed to have the correct values. Increase the time and do more than one reading. ignore the first one.

Comment: The source is a voltage divider connected to the battery, but its impedance should not matter as the VIN voltage is the voltage at the VBAT pin, so only the internal circuitry should matter.
The sampling time is already at the highest value, and the measured value is not dependent on the voltage connected to the channel that is converted before the VBAT channel, so I don't think the charging time of the sampling capacitor is the problem. But to make sure I will try lowering the ADC clock and doing multiple VBAT measurements like you suggested.

Comment: Whatever the error cause is, if it only affects accuracy of Vbat, anything below 1V is dead anyways.

Comment: I am using the ADC to measure an input voltage which is connected to VBAT through a voltage divider, so I need it to be accurate down to about 0.7V. Using a regular ADC channel is not an option unfortunately, as they are all needed for something else. I could fix the error in software but I would prefer finding and fixing the actual cause if possible.

Comment: Lowering the clock and sampling multiple times before using the result does not change the value, so the high impedance of the internal voltage divider and the charging time of the sampling capacitor are not the problem.

Comment: Are you measuring the voltage at the actual Vin pin? I mean, there is a direct, all-copper connection from where you are measuring to the ADC input? No resistors or buffers or any other circuitry in series?

Comment: If this is a special VBAT pin, not a standard ADC pin, they might have not bothered to make it work below 1V.

Comment: It seems that you did nothing wrong and your expectation is valid. This is something you should take up with ST directly. I am sure they have a Field Application Engineer that can help. Or if not, a forum where the question can be posed and answered by someone from ST.

Comment: Yes, I measured directly at the pin. I contacted ST and they basically just replied "You are using the VBAT pin outside of its specifications (below minimum voltage)". So it seems that the pin is not directly connected to the ADC via a voltage divider but via a circuit that doesn't work below 1V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it *could* be noise related. Assuming it is you can try:

- Setting a longer sample time on the ADC and see if the lower end values improve. If that improves somewhat then maybe even take 4-5 readings and average them (potentially ignoring the first).
- Measuring the input to the ADC with a scope and see if there really is a noise floor of around 0.5v (seems odd but depending what else is on the circuit)
- Potentially check whether there is a seperate power supply pin for the ADC. VREF or AVCC it's sometimes called but depends on the chip. (I know some STM32 chips have this) and attach caps and ferrites to make the reference voltage cleaner.
- Worst case try and use an external ADC pin to your battery and see if thats better. If it is then it seems unique to the internal VBAT ADC circuitry which could be an STM problem and not your own. (Check the errata documents for your chip. They will normally publish known issues there)

Comment: The sample time is already at the highest value and the measured noise is much lower than 0.5V. The other ADC pins work fine, but unfortunately all of them are used for something else so I have to use the VBAT pin.
I think the the VBAT pin is not directly connected to the ADC via a voltage divider (like it is described in the datasheet) but via a circuit that doesn't work below 1V. The errata does not mention this but when contacting ST I got the answer "You are using the VBAT pin outside of its specifications (below minimum voltage)". So I guess I will not be able to get it to work.

Comment: Yep, looking at the data sheet you are using it below its limits.